# VBA, Dynamically pickup a date

Tags: vba

I have a file I want to pickup from the previous wednesday June 10th. I will be running my code today (Sunday June 14th). However this will reoccur every week.

Is there a way I can make my code dynamic enough to pickup the previous wednesday date?

Here is my code `Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\extract\Business_Report_20200527.xlsx")`

Can I alter that path to dynamically pickup a date?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to pickup the last Wednesday date independent of the calling date, or only if it happens on Sunday? And your example does not keep a name as I would expect. I would think it like 'Business_Report_20200610.xlsx'. Is it something I am missing...?

Comment: Sunday is irrelevant. So each week it would go like 0527, 0604, 0611 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim today As Date
Dim IntervalType As String
Dim FilePath As String
today = Date()
IntervalType = "d"

While Weekday(today) <> vbWednesday
    today = DateAdd(IntervalType, -1, today)
Wend

FilePath = "C:\extract\Business_Report_" + Format(today, "yyyymmdd") + ".xlsx"
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
```

Comment: 'today', 'IntervalType` and `FilePath` are not objects. I would suggest you to eliminate `Set` in front of them, when allocate values. Otherwise, VBA will return an error... Otherwise, the code looks nice. I will vote it up.

Comment: with sebastians code I get error object required. Now I remove `Set` on FilePath and wbTarget , but now getting an object required on today. How do I go about this?

Comment: I enumerated the variables where Set is inappropriat... Do the same for 'today', too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox "Last Wednesday:  " & PreviousWednesday & vbCr & _
           "Wednesday prior to 9th June:  " & PreviousWednesday(DateValue("9 June 2020")) & vbCr & _
           "Last Wednesday formatted: " & Format(PreviousWednesday, "yyyymmdd")

    'Your code:
    'Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\extract\Business_Report_" & Format(PreviousWednesday, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx")
End Sub

Public Function PreviousWednesday(Optional CurrentDate As Date) As Date
    If CurrentDate = 0 Then CurrentDate = Date
    PreviousWednesday = (CurrentDate - Weekday(CurrentDate, vbMonday) + 1) - 5
End Function
```